# Hadoop Map Reduce - how to separate grouping from sorting?

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, hash, mapreduce

Just getting started writing Hadoop MR jobs.  Hopefully we'll be switching over to Spark soon, but we're stuck doing MR for now.

I'd like to group records by a hash of their value.  But I'd like to sort them by something totally unrelated--a timestamp in their value.  I'm confused about how to best do that.  I see two options:

1)  Have a first MR job that computes the hash for each value in its mapper, and then reduces all the records of that hash to the same value however it wants (I actually have this much working just as we need right now).  Then chain a second MR job that re-sorts the output of the reducer above by the timestamp in the value.  Inefficient?

2)  I've read some blogs/posts about how to use composite keys, so maybe I could accomplish it all in one step?  I'd create some kind of composite key that had both the hash for grouping, and the timestamp for sorting in the mapper.  But I'm unclear if this is possible.  Can it still group correctly if the sort is completely unrelated to the grouping?  Also unsure what interfaces I'd need to implement and what classes I'd need to create or how to configure it.

I'm not talking about a secondary sort.  I don't care about the order of the objects in the Iterator for each reduce call.  I'm concerned with the order things get emitted from reducer, needs to be a global sort by timestamp.

Whats the recommended way to do something like this?

Comment: Does your reducer need to do anything except aggregate by hash, sort and display? Also, you don't care about the order of the hashes, but all the records for the same hash must be sorted, correct?

Comment: My reduce() only needs to aggregate by hash.  But I'd like the output from all the reduce calls to be sorted by timestamp.  I don't need all records of the same hash sorted.  I need the cumulative output of the reducer sorted by timestamp.  This timestamp could come from any of the values in the iterator of reduce().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely possible if you can have a compound key that encapsulates both grouping and sorting properties **prior** to reduce.

Let's say you need a key that holds int hash code and long timestamp. Then you need to implement a writable tuple (say IntLongPair) where you can define all sorts of comparators and partitioners required for your use case.

So you set up your job as something like this (I will get back to possible IntLongPair implementation later):

```
job.setPartitionerClass(IntLongPair.IntOnlyPartitioner.class); //partition by your hash code stored in the int part of the part
job.setGroupingComparatorClass(IntLongPair.IntAscComparator.class); //your hash code grouping - perhaps does not matter ascending or descending
job.setSortComparatorClass(IntLongPair.IntDescLongAscComparator.class); //assuming you need newest items first
```

L

And here is the IntLongPair you can use:

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.RawComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;

public class IntLongPair implements WritableComparable<IntLongPair> {

    private IntWritable intVal = new IntWritable();
    private LongWritable longVal = new LongWritable();

    public void write(DataOutput d) throws IOException {
        intVal.write(d);
        longVal.write(d);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput di) throws IOException {
        intVal.readFields(di);
        longVal.readFields(di);
    }

    /**
     * Natural order is int first, long next
     * @param o
     * @return
     */
    public int compareTo(IntLongPair o) {
        int diff = intVal.compareTo(o.intVal);
        if (diff != 0) {
            return diff;
        }
        return longVal.compareTo(o.longVal);
    }

    public IntWritable getInt() {
        return intVal;
    }

    public void setInt(IntWritable intVal) {
        this.intVal = intVal;
    }

    public void setInt(int intVal) {
        this.intVal.set(intVal);
    }

    public LongWritable getLong() {
        return longVal;
    }

    public void setLong(LongWritable longVal) {
        this.longVal = longVal;
    }

    public void setLong(long longVal) {
        this.longVal.set(longVal);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final IntLongPair other = (IntLongPair) obj;
        if (this.intVal != other.intVal && (this.intVal == null || !this.intVal.equals(other.intVal))) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.longVal != other.longVal && (this.longVal == null || !this.longVal.equals(other.longVal))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.intVal != null ? this.intVal.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.longVal != null ? this.longVal.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IntLongPair{" + intVal + ',' + longVal + '}';
    }

    public IntWritable getFirst() {
        return intVal;
    }

    public LongWritable getSecond() {
        return longVal;
    }

    public void setFirst(IntWritable value) {
        intVal.set(value.get());
    }

    public void setSecond(LongWritable value) {
        longVal.set(value.get());
    }


    public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator {

        public Comparator() {
            super(IntLongPair.class);
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            return compareBytes(b1, s1, l1, b2, s2, l2);
        }
    }

    static {                                        // register this comparator
        WritableComparator.define(IntLongPair.class, new Comparator());
    }

    public static class IntDescLongAscComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            int comp = IntWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1, 4, b2, s2, 4);
            if (comp != 0) {
                return -comp;
            }
            return LongWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1 + 4, 8, b2, s2 + 4, 8);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            int comp = o1.getInt().compareTo(o2.getInt());
            if (comp != 0) {
                return -comp;
            }
            return o1.getLong().compareTo(o2.getLong());
        }
    }

    public static class LongAscIntAscComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            int comp = LongWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1 + 4, 8, b2, s2 + 4, 8);
            if (comp != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
            return IntWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1, 4, b2, s2, 4);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            int comp = o1.getLong().compareTo(o2.getLong());
            if (comp != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
            return  o1.getInt().compareTo(o2.getInt());
        }
    }

    public static class LongAscIntDescComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            int comp = LongWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1 + 4, 8, b2, s2 + 4, 8);
            if (comp != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
            return -IntWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1, 4, b2, s2, 4);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            int comp = o1.getLong().compareTo(o2.getLong());
            if (comp != 0) {
                return comp;
            }
            return -o1.getInt().compareTo(o2.getInt());
        }
    }

    public static class LongDescIntAscComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            int comp = LongWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1 + 4, 8, b2, s2 + 4, 8);
            if (comp != 0) {
                return -comp;
            }
            return IntWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1, 4, b2, s2, 4);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            int comp = o1.getLong().compareTo(o2.getLong());
            if (comp != 0) {
                return -comp;
            }
            return o1.getInt().compareTo(o2.getInt());
        }
    }

    public static class LongDescIntDescComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            int comp = LongWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1 + 4, 8, b2, s2 + 4, 8);
            if (comp != 0) {
                return -comp;
            }
            return -IntWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1, 4, b2, s2, 4);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            int comp = o1.getLong().compareTo(o2.getLong());
            if (comp != 0) {
                return -comp;
            }
            return -o1.getInt().compareTo(o2.getInt());
        }
    }

    public static class IntAscComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            return IntWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1, 4, b2, s2, 4);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            return o1.getInt().compareTo(o2.getInt());
        }
    }

    public static class IntDescComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            return -IntWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1, 4, b2, s2, 4);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            return -o1.getInt().compareTo(o2.getInt());
        }
    }

    public static class LongAscComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            return LongWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1 + 4, 8, b2, s2 + 4, 8);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            return o1.getLong().compareTo(o2.getLong());
        }
    }

    public static class LongDescComparator implements RawComparator<IntLongPair> {

        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            return -LongWritable.Comparator.compareBytes(b1, s1 + 4, 8, b2, s2 + 4, 8);
        }

        public int compare(IntLongPair o1, IntLongPair o2) {
            return -o1.getLong().compareTo(o2.getLong());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Partition based on the long part of the pair.
     */
    public static class LongOnlyPartitioner extends Partitioner<IntLongPair, Writable> {

        @Override
        public int getPartition(IntLongPair key, Writable value,
                int numPartitions) {
            return Math.abs(key.getLong().hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numPartitions;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Partition based on the int part of the pair.
     */
    public static class IntOnlyPartitioner extends Partitioner<IntLongPair, Writable> {

        @Override
        public int getPartition(IntLongPair key, Writable value,
                int numPartitions) {
            return Math.abs(key.getInt().hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numPartitions;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just needed confirmation that its possible before going off the deep end with Composite Keys.  Once I get it working, I'll come back and mark it as answered.

Comment: No problem - I just had this class handy written for one of my previous projects, so thought would be worth to share as it contains some rather boring code required for raw binary comparison.

Comment: From reading the blogs, I was concerned that if I changed up the sort to timestamp, then it would no longer be able to group correctly by hash, but this is not the case, right?  Btw, thanks a lot for the code.

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention to your specific remark on secondary sorting. This is indeed a secondary sort solution, as grouping itself is based on primary sort order. Also there was a mistake with the choice of the sort comparator, it has to be a tuple comparator like IntDescLongAscComparator to make it really work. (I made a correction).

Comment: Let me know if it is not really what you looking for, I will delete the post then.

Comment: Yeah, well, you did answer my question, so no need to delete the answer.  It sounds like I can't do what I want with a compound key, and I'll need to chain an additional sort MR job after the hash MR job.